# Who is the 'One' in the below statement?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

> Legolas says : " It was a balrog of Morgoth, of elf banes the most deadly save the ONE who sits in the Dark Tower "

Now does the "One" in the above statement mean to be Sauron or a Balrog  ?

Answer (score 10):

As the quote states, the One in question "sits in the Dark Tower," i.e., Barad-dûr.  Sauron meets this criterion, but Balrogs do not.

Comment: I have a feeling that elf banes specifically talk about Balrogs; Balrogs have killed a lot of elves  (silmarillion) but there isn't any mention where Sauron commits mass elf massacre. Elves overthrew Sauron at the end of the Second Age so I don't know why they would be afraid of Him. What's more, Baradur is a 'tower of fire' and it seems to indicate that there is a Balrog in the tower who fuels the fire. .

Comment: Not all the Balrogs or to say - the servants of Morgoth died at the hands of the Valar. : Sauron survived and so did Durin's Bane, so it makes sense to assume more of them survived

Comment: @TheMadHatter you're right that the elf banes includes the Balrogs, but wrong in the idea that it was specifically about Balrogs. The elf banes are all the servants of Morgoth who fought against the elves. Sauron was Melkors right hand man and more powerful than any Balrog. I'm not sure where you get this idea that there is a Balrog in the tower but it is absolute nonsense. Finally, towards the end of Tolkien's life he reduced the numbers of Balrogs from thousands to Seven. It is unlikely others survived the War of Wrath and the Sinking of Beleriand.

Comment: Sauron also did considerably more to earn the title 'Elf-Bane' than any Balrog, being Dark Lord for 6,000 years and with things like the War of the Elves and Sauron (which he would have won without Numenorean intervention), and the War of the Last Alliance among other things.  He caused the Elves far more trouble than anyone other than Morgoth, far more than any Balrog.